# In C++, is there any way for variatic template to ignore non-arithmetic type or object and return the sum of remain parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to realize a function as the question title described, for example:

```
cout << SumValue("abc", string("abcd"), 1.3, 1, 10, 2, 100) << endl;
```

I want that C++ snippet output `114.3`, the sum of `1.3, 1, 10, 2 and 100`, and ignore `"abc"` and `string("abcd")`.
I have tried the variatic template function and used the `<type_traits>` lib as codes below:

```
template <typename T>
long double SumValue(T first)
{
  if (is_arithmetic<T>::value)
    return first;
  else
    return 0;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
long double SumValue(T first, Args... args)
{
  if (is_arithmetic<T>::value)
    return first + SumValue(args...);
  else
    return SumValue(args...);
}
```

But compiler reports an error:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'long double' to binary 'operator+'
     return first + SumValue(args...);
            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can understand the error described, but, I cannot figure out a solution for it.

Comment: You need `if constexpr` instead of "normal" `if`.

Comment: ... But that's only available from C++17 on, question is tagged (rightly or wrongly) C++11.

Comment: are you really using C++11? It can be done in C++11, but it is sooo much less code to write when you can upgrade to C++17

Comment: Sorry about the C++ version, I'm a new leaner, don't know so much about the details.

Comment: It's very likely that your compiler supports C++17, but you might need to enable it via a command line switch - `-std=c++17` for gcc and clang.  `if constexpr` is certainly simpler than SFINAE in a simple case like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overload `SumValue` with the help of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, long double>::type
SumValue(T first)
{
  return first;
}
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, long double>::type
SumValue(T first)
{
  return 0;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
long double SumValue(T first, Args... args)
{
  return SumValue(first) + SumValue(args...);
}
```

[LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vKocWTK47)

BTW: Since C++17 you can use [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if).

```
template <typename T>
long double SumValue(T first)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value)
    return first;
  else
    return 0;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
long double SumValue(T first, Args... args)
{
  return SumValue(first) + SumValue(args...);
}
```

[LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M9xd8dobG)